# Declarative syntax for a collection of value types in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, generics, collections, asp.net-2.0, declarative

I know that in ASP.NET (talking about 2.0 here primarily) one can set a property on an object that takes a collection of things (an enumerable type I'm guessing is the trigger) and then reference it declaritivly.  For example:

```
<ObjectDataSource properties="blahblahblah">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter />
    </SelectParameters>
</ObjectDataSource>
```

It is the `<asp:Parameter />` part which is the root of my question.  Say I wanted a simpler collection on a type.  Say a `List<String>` or if generics are out, an IntegerCollection or StringCollection.  How would I use that declaratively?  Is `<string value=''>` allowed, or can I put raw values into it like `<StringCollection>string, string, string</StringCollection>` or what?

EDIT:

I feel like I was not clear enough in my question.  I understand that ObjectDataSource implements its SelectParameters property as a ParametersCollection, and that one can use that property declaratively (in an ASPX page) to set up Parameter types within that collection.  What I'm wondering is if I made something like StringCollection as a property on another control, is there a syntax (in ASPX) for adding strings to that collection?  Or would I have to define a wrapping class like how DropDownList takes ListItems to fill its collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found what I needed for this.  The general answer is to use a TypeConverter attribute on the property.  The GridView does this with (as one example) DataKeyNames, converting a comma separated list of names in a string into an array of strings.

Answer (score 1):

In an objectdatasource the selectparameter refers to a parameter in a method that returns a collection.  That parameter needs to be something that can be converted from a string, it cannot be a collection or an array.